# Is there a sugar syntax for this HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have one to many mapping,  School with set of Students and I want to get just the schools in which all students have score greater the 3.
Following query did the job:

```
List list = session.createQuery("select school from School school join school.students st group by school.id having min(st.score) > 3").list();
```

But I'm wondering is there a shorter way, something like HQL build-in function to get same result.

Comment: Well, I don't know what you really mean by 'syntax sugar'. You can use JPA/Hibernate criteria api if you prefer more object oriented way. Also, consider http://www.querydsl.com/.

Comment: By "syntax sugar" I mean shorter way to do the same query, HQL build -in function. I dont't want to do group by and having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a subquery:

```
select school from School school where not exists(
    select student.id from School school2 
    join school2.students student 
    where student.score <= 3 
    and school2.id = school.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering on down-voted question. Is there a HQL build-in function which will get the same result, may be something like "select s from School s join s.students st where all(st.score) > 3".